Semi-supervised learning - focus on incorrectly predicted examples
For sake of simplicity I have a series of images and I'm trying to detect if it is of a cat. I've got a small set of completely labelled images - half of them containing a cat, and half not - and a much larger set of batches of images, where I only know whether the batch contains an image of a cat.
I'm thinking that a good way of increasing the accuracy would be the following method

On a correctly identified batch - do nothing
A false positive (cat identified on empty batch) - add false positives to training data
A false negative (no cat identified for batch that contains cat) - add possible cats for manual review

If I do this, I expect it to:

Be more resilient to edge cases by reducing the overfitting on the most common type of cat
Be self rightening - if it strays too much from e.g. the most common type of cat, then it will start getting more false negatives - bringing it back into line

Is there a name for this kind of process, and, will it increase the accuracy as I expect?
